# Leer con T-SQL información de diagramas creados en SQLServer

Tags: sql-server-2008, tsql

¿Existe alguna tabla en el sqlserver donde se puedan leer los diagramas que se hayan creado en una base de datos, asi como las tablas que se incluyeron?

Comment: Leer diagramas? No entiendo muy bien tu pregunta. Quieres saber cuales son los diagramas que tiene creada una base de datos? De ser así solo ve al nodo de "DataBase Diagrams" y dentro podrás visualizar los diagramas creados.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes consultar los existentes en la tabla

> sysdiagrams

```
SELECT *
FROM  sysdiagrams s
```

Para obtener más información sobre los diagramas puedes utilizar los procedimientos

> sp_alterdiagram sp_dropdiagram sp_creatediagram sp_renamediagram
>   sp_helpdiagramdefinition sp_helpdigarms sp_upgradediagrams

Que quizá te ayuden.